# Is `\strip@pt` removing the hundreds as well as the `pt`?

Tags: dimension-expressions

I was getting some strange results trying to position things in beamer, and I realised that `\strip@pt` was removing not only the `pt`, but also the hundreds from the number.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testOne}{\dimexpr100pt\relax}
\newcommand{\testTwo}{\strip@pt\dimexpr100pt\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \the\testOne

        \the\testTwo
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

This is a bug, right? Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

For the record, I need to remove the dimensions to avoid a warning from `\putat`. In case this is an XY problem, I'm open for suggestions on better ways to position things on the slide.

Comment: it's not `\strip@pt` removing the 1, but the `\the` that you added (as the error message shows)

Comment: `\the\testTwo` yields `\the\strip@pt\dimexpr100pt\relax` yields `\the100` . Here `\the` does not find that kind of expression it expects but the digit `1` and thus delivers an error-message and the digit `0`, so in the end you have an error-message and the sequence `000`. So the answer is: It is not a bug. You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an error message you should not even look at the generated PDF.  the posted document produces

```
! You can't use `the character 1' after \the.
<argument> 1
            00
l.13     \end{frame}

?
```

You can not use `\the` on `100`

```
\documentclass[]{beamer} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testOne}{\dimexpr100pt\relax}
\newcommand{\testTwo}{\strip@pt\dimexpr100pt\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \the\testOne

        \testTwo
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]